# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on namespace string

Tags: php

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ...Ping.php on line 3

In code:

```
<?php

namespace JJG; // line 3

class Ping {

  private $host;
  private $ttl;
//...
}
```

I expect the class will work fine, as provided https://github.com/geerlingguy/Ping

But the actual output is:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ...Ping.php on line 3

Comment: You seem to have removed the file header comment from the `Ping.php` file (the `namespace JJG;` should be [line 24](https://github.com/geerlingguy/Ping/blob/1.x/JJG/Ping.php#L24)). What else have you changed?

Comment: I remove all exclude code above. Just becouse there is error.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I take it.

On this server PHP Version can be only 5.2.5, and seems like there is no full support of namespaces in it yet.

Comment: The namespaces where [introduced in PHP 5.3](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php). Which is dead and buried since years ago. Upgrade to PHP 7.2 or newer. The older versions are [not maintained any more](https://php.net/supported-versions.php).